# Unattended install of gui-installer over intune

Tags: windows, powershell, unattended, silent-install, intune

Right now, I'm packaging some piece of software `intune` for which the developers didn't intend a silent-install-mode. Without a silent-install the manual rollout of this software would be very tiresome. The installation-routine is rather easy. I just need to start the software and press `Enter` in a certain interval. It is no big deal.

I've played around with the python-package `pyautogui` and I'm aware of the existence of `AutoIt`, but I want to realize the task without any dependencies. I just want to work with given windows-utilities.

I've come up with this script.

```
Write-Host "Starting program Setup..."
Write-Host "$PWD\SETUP.EXE"

Start-Process -FilePath "$PWD\SETUP.EXE"

Write-Host "Sleepin' 40 secs'..."
Start-Sleep 40

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
# Not needed because focus goes automatically there
# $wshell.AppActivate('Installer Windows Title')
Start-Sleep 10
Write-Host "Sleepin' 10 secs'..."
$wshell.SendKeys('~') # Enter
Write-Host "Sleepin' 20 secs'..."
Start-Sleep 20
$wshell.SendKeys('~') # Enter


Write-Host "Sleepin' 5 secs'..."
Start-Sleep 5


if (Test-Path "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\my-program.lnk" ){
    Write-Host "progam-install was successful!"
}else{
    Write-Host "program-install was not successful..."
}
```

The sleeping is for the time in between when `SETUP.EXE` is running their task.

On my local machine with administrative rights, the program gets installed successfully. Deployed via an `intune`-package the GUI will not open and the program won't get installed.

Is it even possible for gui-installer to open when deployed over `intune`? By the intune-option `Install Behavior` the install is done via `System`. Could this be an issue? Does anyone got experience with such a task?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the installer has no silent install switch? If you want to go the silent route, you should look into packaging it into an .msi. That means, getting a clean windows install (through Windows sandbox for example) make a baseline, install, make a snapshot, and create an installer that makes all changes that were found.

Comment: So you are saying, I can make my own msi packages by collecting information from a snapshot? If so, can you please provide more information on this?

Comment: I know its possible to do it like that, but it has been years since I last worked with this. My colleague build these so I know its still possible, but he always first looks for the /silent /hidden /quiet etc install switch and almost never has to actually go the route of making his own installer.